# What's the best way to notate this syncopation?

Tags: notation, syncopation

Trying to write out the first measure to "When I Get Low I Get High", I've read this answer, https://music.stackexchange.com/a/59262/63723, is this the best approach?

[image]

Comment: I agree that this is the best way - as I‘ve learnt it like this! ;) The criteria was: the half or the middle of the bar should be recognizable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what's  in the picture. All major subdivisions are respected so one can play it at sight. The tied Cs make it clear that there is a note held from beat 2 to beat 3.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment: make the middle of the bar visible.

But ths will be difficult in a 3/8 like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncopation

[image]